# how do I build a single project in code::blocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I tried to compile and execute a file outside a project.
But when I hit F9, the main file in the active project was built.

How do I build and run a single file project?

Reading [this article](http://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CGUQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Flatedev.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F12%2F07%2Ften-codeblocks-tips%2F&ei=JZu3Ud_4MMXliAfJoYDoDA&usg=AFQjCNEmHpJjTdb1BlwIeUrKeMwSJZ1cFQ&sig2=bc63VZYa0I5SE9Pa6yo6ZA&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aGc) it seemed possible, but it didn't tell me how.

Comment: just open the file with C::B and press F9, with no projects opened

Comment: @calccrypto it works for one file, but then when I open move to the tab with another file, it just opens to previous file. I tried clicking inside the tab, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: that shouldnt be happening

Comment: I got it fixed now. I think the problem was that I had another project opened.
So does this mean that Code::Blocks puts the active project at the top of the list for build, and any attempts to build individual files are overridden?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can compile the file outside the project but you can't run it through codeblocks. If project is already open in codeblocks then pressing <kbd>f9</kbd> or **build and run** button it compile and run the current project. If you have a c/c++ source file outside the project and you want to compile it then at first select the file you want to compile, **go to menu and press -> build -> compile current file or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>**. But you can't run it through codeblocks so you have to run executable file directly from the directories where .exe file has been build.